# Grid input area

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface

I am looking for a way that my client would be able to 'paste' data to a grid area input, an 'Excel' kind of asp.net control.

For example, suggest I have a list of Emails and Clients in an XLS file, and I would like to copy them to my page's grid, and then store this Data to my database.

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download it from [Sigma Grid](http://www.sigmawidgets.com/download.html). It's a good one.